# PHP: Notice undefined index only when I open it in a new tab

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I have an "events calendar" that when I click on a specific date, it redirects me to a page that shows all the events within that day. This works perfectly fine, but for some reason when I open the link with a new tab, it gives me the PHP Notice stating that these are undefined in the controller:

```
public function actionEventPerDay()
{
    $year = $_GET['year']; //undefined in a new tab
    $month=$_GET['month']; //undefined in a new tab
    $day =$_GET['day']; //undefined in a new tab
    $date = $year.'/'.$month.'/'.$day;
    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Content', array(
            'criteria' => array(
                    'select'=>'*',
                    'condition' => 'node_type_id=5 and DATE_FORMAT(date(start_date), "%Y %m %d")= DATE_FORMAT("'.$date.'", "%Y %m %d")',

            ),
        'pagination' => array(
          'pagesize' => 10,
        ),
    )); 

    $this->render('index', array('dataProvider' => $dataProvider));

}
```

My events calendar is generated using ajax:

```
  <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    dataType:'json',
                    url:'<?php echo $this->createUrl('/events/renderJson'); ?>',
                    success:function(data) {
                        //alert(data[0].title);
                        //var eventsInline = data;//[ { "date": "2013-08-30 17:30:00", "type": "meeting", "title": "Test Last Year", "description": "Lorem Ipsum dolor set", "url": "" },{ "date": "2013-09-01 17:30:00", "type": "meeting", "title": "Test Last Year", "description": "Lorem Ipsum dolor set", "url": "" }];
                        $("#eventCalendarDiv").eventCalendar({
                            jsonData: data,
                            url:'<?php echo $this->createAbsoluteUrl('/events/eventperday'); ?>',
                            link:'<?php echo $this->createAbsoluteUrl('/events/eventpermonth'); ?>'
                        });
                    },
                    error:function(request){
                        //salert(request.responseText);
                        //alert('error');
                    }
                });


            });
            </script>
```

My code works fine unless I open the link in a new tab.

Comment: Your request method is `POST` in your AJAX but looking at `$_GET` in your PHP?

Comment: It is possible to send a POST request and get parameters from $_GET. for example, if the request sends to myrequest.php?date=2014-2-1, with a POST form data, then $_GET['date'] is populated. To debug the issue, check the exact request being sent, and see whether the query string is parsed correctly. Undefined index error means the $_GET array key is uninitialized.

Comment: did you look at `var_dump($_GET)`? Is the url for the new tabs actually including those parameters, and/or is your server-side rewrite stuff creating them?

Comment: You could make use of [**sessions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Comment: I used the `var_dump($_GET)` in the controller and nothing is being passed over when creating a new tab. 

@Fred-ii- a session is already in place.

Comment: @user3278616, does the error message provide a line number or the name of the index it is complaining about?